# DANFE em Jasper - problema com o campo dados adicionais

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport, jasper, jaspersoft-studio

Tenho um relatório DANFE desenvolvido em Jasper e preciso que as informações do campo "Dados Adicionais" sejam impressas. Porém, quando há estouro deste campo o mesmo não imprime o restante das informações na próxima página, mas imprime o campo desde o início, deixando-o com as mesmas informações em todas as páginas.

No Campo estou utilizando as seguintes propriedades:

- Stretch With Overflow: true;
- Stretch Type: Relative to Tallest Object;
- Position Type: Float;
- Print When Detail Overflows: False;

O campo está na Band Page Footer, que está com a opção "Split Type" como "Prevent" e já tentei utilizar como "Stretch" mas não resolveu o problema.

Desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara, é o seguinte, o Page Footer só imprime uma única vez em cada pagina, para que os seus Dados Adicionais quebram de página você tem duas opções: ou você coloca seu campo de Dados Adicionais em um novo Detail, ou crie um Group.
Os dois continuará na próxima página como tu quer, já o Page Footer se reseta a cada iteração de página.